# Fetch data from a nested array which has no key, just values to populate multiple selects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, populate

I have a JSON file, and I made a first variable that takes the countries out of it. These countries have cities inside them, this is the variable with that data:

```
var sucursalPais = [
    "colombia": [
        "bogotá",
        "cali"
    ],
    "peru" : [
        "lima",
        "cusco"
    ]
]
```

now, I am populating two select tags; one with country names, using this:

```
for (var k in sucursalPais) {
    pais.innerHTML += '<option value ="' + k + '">' + k +'</option>';
}
```

So, when a pick a country, the next select is suposed to be populated by that country cities; but I don't know how to call the cities into the next select, because I don't have a city [] subarray with all of them on it, I have directly the cities into each country.

I have tried all, but I have not found a solution.

This is all of my code:

```
var pais = document.getElementById("pais");
var sucursalPais = [];

for (z = 0; z < sucursalData.length; z++) {
    if(sucursalData[z].content.country && sucursalData[z].content.city) {
        if(sucursalPais[sucursalData[z].content.country] != undefined) {
            sucursalPais[sucursalData[z].content.country].push(sucursalData[z].content.city);
        } else {
            sucursalPais[sucursalData[z].content.country] = [sucursalData[z].content.city];
        }
    }
}
for (var k in sucursalPais){
    pais.innerHTML += '<option value ="' + k + '">' + k +'</option>';
}
pais.addEventListener("change", function () {
    for (m = 0; m < pais[this.value].length; m++) {
        console.log(sucursalPais[m]);
        ciudad.innerHTML += '<option value ="' + sucursalPais[m][value] + '">' + sucursalPais[m][value] +'</option>';
    }
});
```

Comment: your json file is invalid. array elements cannot have keys in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what a **pais** is, but you'll get the point:

```
sucursalPais = {
    "colombia": [
        "bogotá",
        "cali"
    ],
    "peru" : [
        "lima",
        "cusco"
    ]
}

var pais = "";
var pius = "";

for (var k in sucursalPais) {
  pais += '<option value ="' + k + '">' + k +'</option>';

  for (var z=0; z < sucursalPais[k].length; z++) {
    var city = sucursalPais[k][z];
    pius += '<option value ="' + city + '">' + city +'</option>';
  }
}

console.log(pais); // Countries
console.log(pius); // Cities
```

... you can create **pius** with **innerHTML** like in your example, I use strings to make the demo simple.